# Could we show data in text of percona graph in zabbix

Tags: mysql, zabbix, percona

I am using percona plugin in zabbix 3.0 for MySQL server and want to know is there any way I can show the graph data in text form for MySQL server like these queries are slow and these are creating deadlocks or locking tables.

Comment: Does the Percona solution expose that as Zabbix items? If yes, you can probably display that, although I'm not sure what you refer to with "show the graph data in text form" in this context.

Comment: I can more elaborate like right now graphs are good and giving output that X number of deadlocks occurs but I cannot find which tables or queries create these deadlocks.

Comment: Any input to that ?

Comment: Sounds like this is about debugging performance issues. You could implement separate items to collect slow queries and the like. You won't be able to show any data like that on a graph, though.

Comment: I am collecting data for slow queries and result was good. But the major challenge is when any deadlock occurs. I want a tool which can alert proactively that deadlock occurs or which table/query is locked.

Comment: That's a different question, though - the original question was about showing some text data on a graph. You can collect that data, and include it in emails that Zabbix sends, for example.

Comment: You should read the question statement again :)